# Drawing using Quartz 2D on a uiimageview - lines getting blurry

Tags: ios, xcode, drawing, core-graphics, cgcontext

This is a question related to drawing paths (in response to touch events) using Core Graphics in a view for an iPad application.

I have a view as a part of a scrollview where I want to trace the path of touch.  The code below works for other uiimageviews in the app but not for this particular subview.  As I draw (by tracing/touching on the screen), the lines appear but start moving in the y-direction.  So, the whole trace keeps getting compressed in y-direction!!  As the lines move up, they also seem to diffuse and eventually disappear!

The same code works fine for a different view outside the scrollview.  I have searched online for the past 3 days and spend hours trying to understand what is going on here but I still have no clue.  Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Here is my code for drawing:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(coverIVFragments.frame.size);
            [coverIVFragments.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, coverIVFragments.frame.size.width, coverIVFragments.frame.size.height)];
            CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 2.0);
            CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
            CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
            CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), x1, y1);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), x2, y2);
            CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

            coverIVFragments.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should be using the new method that takes a scale instead of UIGraphicsBeginImageContext (on iPad no Xcode handy).

Probably the issue is interaction with the scroll view. At the top of your routine log the scrollviews contentOffset and your frame. You are assuming a 0,0 origin all the time but really the frame you want may well be a combo of sv.contentOffset and the sv.bounds.size.

For me I often log this kind of issue and it becomes apparent real soon what I need to do.

EDIT: you problem is using non-integral rects - this line corrects the problem with no zooming:

```
   coverImageView.frame = CGRectIntegral(coverImageView.frame);
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(coverImageView.frame.size, NO, imageScrollView.zoomScale);
```

I don't think you are using the 'scale' parameter correctly - probably you should resize the rectangle that drawing will go into, and just use scale for its intended purpose and pass '0' there.

Comment: Thanks David.  I have a uiimageview outside the scrollview from where I take the touch events and then draw the lines on the image view that is subview of the scrollview.  I was hoping that will prevent any interference with the scrollview.  when I log the scroll view and its subview bounds, and offsets, they appear fine.  I did find that the issue goes away when I zoom to the max - so somehow the zoomscale is affecting the drawing (only in the y -direction and not in the x-direction).

Comment: I am also disabling the userinteraction for the scrollview and was hoping that should prevent any changes in the bound/offsets during drawing.

Comment: If you cannot figure it out, then you need to post a demo app on DropBox or equiv and let others take a look at it This will take some time on your part but is likely to end with info on how to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks David.  Here is the sample code:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/b885wdhls8ztmbk/testDraw.zip  Let me know if you have any problems in running this.

Comment: Thanks.  I end up removing the view where I am doing drawing from the srollview.  This work more or less but the drawing becomes very slow when zoomed into the image.  Also, the issue of lines getting blurry has not gone completely.  I will appreciate if you could have a look at this and suggest some better ways to accomplish this.  Here is the code:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/b885wdhls8ztmbk/testDraw.zip  Let me know if you have any problems in running this.